# How to select first id from button element in XPath?

Tags: html, google-chrome, xpath, xhtml

I am trying to return the first element of my XPath query of and web page and not sure why this is not working in Google Chrome. I have tried various variations but this has been unsuccessful.

The basic example is which in my case returns:

```
INPUT: //button[@data-qtip='Next Page']/@id
OUTPUT: [id=​"button-1135-btnEl",id=​"button-1101-btnEl"]
```

So my guess would be that selecting the first item can be done as follow but none work for me.

```
INPUT: //button[@data-qtip='Next Page' and position() = 1]/@id
OUTPUT: [id=​"button-1135-btnEl",id=​"button-1101-btnEl"]
INPUT: //button[@data-qtip='Next Page']/@id[1]
OUTPUT: [id=​"button-1135-btnEl",id=​"button-1101-btnEl"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> //button[@data-qtip='Next Page']/@id[1]
> ```

**This is one of the most FAQ in XPath**.

The above expression in general doesn't select (only) one node as expected.

The reason?

In the **[W3C XPath Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)** the `//` abbreviation is defined in such a way that this pseudo - operator has a lower precedence than the XPath `[]` operator.

Thus, any expression like:

```
//SomeNode[1]
```

selects all `SomeNode` nodes each of which is the first `SomeNode` child of its parent. In the general case, there might be more than one such nodes.

**When we want to select the first `SomeNode` node in the document, then we must override the default operator precedence by using brackets**:

```
(//SomeNode)[1]
```

**In this particular case use**:

```
(//button[@data-qtip='Next Page']/@id)[1]
```

Comment: To me your text seems to imply that in this case `//` is not similar to any other axis. Maybe I'm misinterpreting it, but if not, then how is it so? After all, a similar problem could also come up, for example, with `child::aa/child::bb[1]`. Isn't this more about that the context position for each node in the (to be filtered) node set is always calculated independently and grouping the expression just changes the context and therefore the way the context position is determined?

Comment: @jasso: `//` is different. In order to best understand its meaning, one needs to get the exact definition form the W3C XPath 1.0 specification. I am at work and will be able to provide a detailed explanation in 6hours' time. In the meantime, if you search the xpath and the xslt tag, you will find two or more detailed and correct answers to your question.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev No hurry, I can wait for days since I may not be able to visit SO until Monday. I have read the XPath spec before and am aware that `//tag` corresponds to `/descendant-or-self::node()/tag`. So the proximity position is in this case defined with respect to (default) child axis, not with respect to the document order of the selected node set, like OP seemed to expect. Isn't this similar to all location paths so that `//` is no exception? (except that it "looks different" :) In other words, predicate never applies to whole set but to current axis, regardless the usage of `//`.

Comment: And again in other words, wouldn't grouping be always needed to change the the axis used for the predicate and the context in which the proximity position is applied to? Or does using `//` make some difference regarding that aspect?

Comment: @jasso: The big difference is obvious if you compare: `//name[1]` with `/descendant::name[1]`. The former selects every `name` element in the document that is the first child of its parent -- potentially many. The latter selects the first (just one or zero) of all `name` elements in the document. As for "grouping", I don't understand what "grouping" has to do with the topic under discussion.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev So I clearly did misinterpret your answer (like I suspected in my first comment) when guessing that you implied that using `//` adds to the precedence rules some new complexity of which I was not aware. Actually I only thought so because it certainly wouldn't have been the first time to learn something new from you. In fact your point was just that using `//` acts differently when compared to descendant axis, because really in `//name[1]` there are syntactically two steps and `name` node is selected from the `child` axis. Sorry for the disturbance and thank you for your time.

Comment: Oh, and as for "grouping"; I was referring to grouping expressions/syntax structures with parenthesis like `A * (B + C)`, not as in "Muenchian grouping" for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try if next xpath command works for you:

```
INPUT: (//button[@data-qtip='Next Page']/@id)[1]
```